# English name for this musical piece?

Tags: translation

I’m making the program booklet, and one thing they are playing is 苏三起解.
Is there a commonly used English name for it?  I have “Su San Under Escort” but see others when I search for it, like “Susan left Hongtong county”.
That’s not a pretty or poetic name.  So is there a better name I should use?
Also, Su San, not [Susan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Susan), right?

---

Also,
[The Story of SU San](http://en.chncpa.org/NEWS/wzxw/201710/t20171017_178104.shtml)
[Susan’s Redemption](http://usa.chinadaily.com.cn/world/2017-06/27/content_29924816.htm)
[Su San Sets Out for a Retrial](https://books.google.com/books?id=EO7LgHBYmHcC&pg=PA114&lpg=PA114&dq=Peking+opera++Su+San&source=bl&ots=eg8seDaE3e&sig=A-D6NP2cqW04iJmz-06vquh9YIw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjb1q2y_rHXAhWEJiYKHZVQBT4Q6AEIZjAP#v=onepage) (But I don’t know if that’s the name of one scene or song within the opera, or the opera itself)
[The Woman Prisoner 女起解](https://www.chinahighlights.com/travelguide/culture/traditional-operas.htm) (does appear to be the name of a specific aria, not the whole opera)

Comment: ＂under escort" seems to refer to the following story, see baike,  苏三受刑不过，只得屈忍画押，被判死刑，禁于死牢之中。适值王景隆出任山西巡按，得知苏三已犯死罪，便密访洪洞县，探知苏三冤情，即令火速    **押解苏三案全部人员到太原**  。

Comment: I'm seeing the title as **Susan Left Hongtong County** mostly here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%B5%B7%E8%A7%A3
>
> 起解” 如果要简单的翻译成现代汉语，那就是：“提审”
>
> If we want to simply translate "起解"  into modern Chinese, it is: "提审"
>
> “提审”。提审程序如果按照目前的诉讼法理论，是上级法院根据自己的意志做出的、对下级法院生效判决重新审理的司法程序 (It means a higher court initiates a retrial of a case that was adjudicated by a lower court)
>
> *起解 also means [start sending prisoner away under escort]∶押送罪犯或货物上*路
>
> *Since Su San was convicted of murder and sentenced to death, there was no reason to send her somewhere else, Therefore, 起解 in 苏三起解 should mean "retrial" not "escort away"*

苏三 is a woman's name (she was the heroine of the Chinese opera 苏三起解)

苏三起解 can be translated as "**The retrial of Su San**"  or "**Exoneration of Su San**"

Answer (score 1):

"起解" should be interpreted as "起程" + "押解".

起程 "start" + "journey" --> to set out, to leave

押解 --> convey under detention

i would suggest, maybe "su's journey under detention".

rationale: "under escort", well, someone would misinterpret it as "escort service", provided by females.

"under detention", implied that subject lost his freedom, constrained by law enforcing agents.

have fun :)